# Blackberry COD build issue

Tags: blackberry, .cod-file

I have a database of size 20MB that I would like to build into COD.
Its a mandated requirement.

How can I get the rapc to build 20MB?

When I build the app  I am getting the compiler error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.d.af.bb(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.d.af.null(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.d.k.for(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.d.aa.p(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.d.aa.a(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler.if(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler.k(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler.a(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler.compile(Unknown Source)
    at net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler.main(Unknown Source)
Fatal Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to have that requirement re-examined. 20MB is larger than available program store (where all installed COD files must reside) on many Blackberries.

Comment: Agreed. Remember that your device in normal use cases is connected.  It would make more sense to host this remotely.

Comment: @Richard, what is the available program store size?

Comment: Available program store memory would be total program store memory less the size of the OS, all installed applications, and all data stored there (persitent store and RMS data). Later models have more memory, but the 8800 series, still in use by many, has only 64MB.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the FileConnection API, and store the file(s) on an SDCard in the device.  You'll have to come up with a solution for initially loading the data (have your app download it, or manually install via USB), but it may be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

For more than 15 years, the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Bug-Criteria.html) has included the sentences "If the compiler gets a fatal signal, for *any input whatever*, that is a compiler bug.  Reliable compilers never crash." (emphasis mine).

You're not using GCC, but the principle still applies.  If 20MB blobs are not supported in COD files, the compiler should tell you so explicitly; it should not crash.  You have found a bug in the compiler, and you should report it to RIM.